# Using a patch to modify drivers for surface pro 3

Tags: drivers, patch, surface

I don't know much about the command line aspect of things and have always been terrible with driver modification and things like that. currently when attempting to apply a patch on ubuntu for my surface pro 3 I am asked "file to patch:". I am trying to get my type cover to work and am following the instructions here, http://blog.davidelner.com/dual-booting-ubuntu-14-10-on-the-surface-pro-3/, but the author doesn't mention anything about which file I should be patching. Also, is this normal for patching or is there something missing in the patch file? Thanks!

Comment: What directory are you running the `patch` command from? is the kernel source that you downloaded the identical version to that in the patch?

Answer (score 1):

No patches required for latest Ubuntu nightly (kernel is 3.10.0-11 currently).  Except battery is not detected, there is a one line patch for that.  To get the touchpad to work, just add this to /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-evdev.conf

```
Section "InputClass"
    Identifier "Surface Pro 3 cover"
    MatchIsPointer "on"
    MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
    Driver "evdev"
    Option "vendor" "045e"
    Option "product" "07dc"
    Option "IgnoreAbsoluteAxes" "True"
EndSection
```